# add spaces at the end of a string before carriage return

Tags: php

I am building a string by concatenating some peices togheter but I run into an issue with adding the end of the string: the string must have a fixed length of 168 chars.
If a condition is met the last 34 chars are a string. If the condition is not met I need to add 34 spaces.
My code is the following:

```
foreach($records as $record){
    if($record['guest'].$record['guests']==11){ //se viaggia uno solo
        $string .='16';
    }else{
        if($record['guest']==1){ //se è il capogruppo
            $string .='18';
        }else{ //se è un membro del gruppo
            $string .='20';
        }
    }
    $string .=$record['checkin']; //data di arrivo
    $string .=str_pad($record['giorni'],2); //2 cifre per i giorni di permanenza
    $string .=str_pad($record['cognome'], 50);
    $string .=str_pad($record['nome'], 30);
    $string .=$record['sesso'];
    $string .=$record['dob'];
    if($record['nazione_nascita']=='100000100'){ //se è nato in italia
        $string .=$record['citta_nascita'];
        $provincia=$pdo->query("SELECT provincia FROM city WHERE codice='{$record['citta_nascita']}'")->fetchColumn(); //recupero la provincia del comune
        $string .=$provincia;
    }else{ 
        $string =str_pad($string,115);
    }
    $string .=$record['nazione_nascita'];
    $string .= $record['nazionalita'];
    if($record['guest']==1){ //cliente ha inserito anche il numero di documento
        $string .=$record['tipoDocumento'];
        $numeroDocumento = str_pad($record['numeroDocumento'],20);
        $string .=$numeroDocumento;
        $string .= $record['citta_documento'];
    }else{ //gli altri ospiti che viaggiano con il capogruppo
        $string = str_pad($string,168);
    }
    $strlen=strlen($string);
    $strActual=$strlen-$strlenTotale;
    $strlenTotale=$strlenTotale+$strActual;
    echo $strActual;
    echo '<pre>'.$totale.' '.$i."\n".'</pre>';
    if($totale!=$i){
        $string .="\r\n";
    }
    $i=$i+1;
}
$schedine = fopen("schedine.txt", "w+");

fwrite($schedine, $string);
fclose($schedine);
```

[image]

As you can see in the picture, line 1 and 3 have $record['guest']==1 and so 168 chars. Line 2 and 4 miss the last 34 spaces.
This code is not attaching the 34 spaces if `$record['guest']!=1`
I expect `$string = str_pad($string,168);` to add the missing 34 spaces but it seems not to work. The end of the string (after the 168 chars) will always be CR+LF, is this that is causing the issue?
How can I fix it?

Comment: As usual your descriuption is a little vague, it would be useful to see roughly what happens before this piece of code is run, specifically to `$string` and also what these other data values are

Comment: I have added the full code, each foreach iteration is a line that must be 168 chars + cr and lf. When $record['guest']!=1 I get 134 instead of 168. I inspect the txt and see that the spaces are clearly missing

Comment: I don't clear it. I calculate the 168 on each line before the cr+lf, sorry this was not clear enough

Comment: I'm deleting my answer. @RiggsFolly is onto something. This is filling up a string with multiple records terminated with \r\n then writing them to a file. Change the code to build a line at a time, get the padding right, then append to the string to output.

Comment: Yep! that's it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a single string into which you load lots of rows... So obviously

```
$string = str_pad($string,168);
```

could only ever work if it was run for the first iteration of your loop, after that `$string` is already greater than 168 chars long.

I would suggest you amend the code to write each line as you complete it to the file, initialise `$string` each time round the loop and then you will be Golden

Comment: it sound soooo obvious now that you spot it! Thanks.... Need to split the file write line by line

Comment: They always are :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Same advice than @RiggsFolly (write a line at a time), and in addition use a formatted string: this way you can prepare the data (in an array) without to worry about paddings. Example:

```
// prepare the statement once and for all before the loop
// Then, when needed, execute it with the required parameter.
// (see the PHP manual for prepared statements)
$query = <<<'SQL'
SELECT provincia
FROM city
WHERE codice=:codice
SQL;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

// Write a formatted string: this way you can assign a length 
// for each part of the line (when needed) using jutifications.
$format = "%s%s%-2s%-50s%-30s%s%s...to_complete...\r\n";

$schedine = fopen('schedine.txt', 'w+');

foreach($records as $record) {

    $data = [];
    
    // store each element of the line in this array
    // when an element is not supposed to appear in
    // the line due to one of your conditions, store
    // an empty string.
    
    if ( $record['guest'] !== 1 ) {
        $data[] = 20;
    } elseif ( $record['guests'] !== 1 ) {
        $data[] = 18;
    } else {
        $data[] = 16;
    }
    
    $data[] = $record['checkin'];
    $data[] = $record['giorni'];
    $data[] = $record['cognome'];
    $data[] = $record['nome'];
    // ...

    fprintf($schedine, $format, ...$data);
    // if your PHP version is too old to support the spread
    // operator ( ...$data ), replace this line with:
    //   $line = vsprintf($format, $data);
    //   fwrite($schedine, $line);

}

fclose($schedine);
```